# Combining a string with a variable in a variable

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to make something that you give a number to, it takes it and divides it in coins that have 5pts and coins that have 1pt. for example if you say i have 41pts it will give you 8 5pt coins and 1 1pt coin. for now i want to say if it's divisible by 5 then give 5pt coins and if it's not give 1pt coins. I've gotten this far

```
    from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
def get_text():
    global number
    numbers = num_textbox.get()
    number = int(numbers)
    print(number)
root = Tk()
root.title("Number Cent Divider")
root.geometry("365x155")
num_col_mat = Label(root, text="Your number:")
num_col_mat.pack()
num_textbox = Entry(root, bd=1)
num_textbox.pack()
enter_button = Button(root, text="Enter", command=add_text)
enter_button.pack()
root.mainloop()
def popup():
    popup = tk.TopLevel()
    popup.wm_title("answer")
    answer = Label(popup, text=answer)
    answer.pack
    B1 = ttk.Button(popup, text="Ok", command=popup.destroy)
    B1.pack()
str(number)
if (number[-1] == 5 or number[-1] == 0):
    answer = num
```

My problem is how I would go about putting variable and a string into another variable.

```
answer = (number, "5pt coins")
```

Is it something similar to this?

Comment: What are you expecting? You should narrow down your issue.

Comment: number % 5 = how many 1 pointers 
floor(number/5) = how many 5 pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the number into string with built in `str` function then concatenate them with `+` operator
or use string formatting like @Błotosmętek suggested

```
number = 10
answer = str(number) + " 5pt coins"
# '10 5pt coins'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
answer = "{} 5pt coins".format(number)
```

Comment: can you explain what .format does and what the { } part is for?

Comment: Please read the appriopriate fragment of documentation, here it is: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Answer (score -1):

You can convert integer into strings using str(number) function in python. After converting number into string you can concatenate two strings using + operator in python.

```
   answer= str(8)+", 5 points"
```

above statement will put "8, 5 points" into answer variable.

Comment: This answer is wrong and misleading. Python *never* implicitly converts integers to strings.

Comment: Sorry , for posting misleading answer. Thnx for correcting @Błotosmętek